# Command to list event monitors in DB2

Tags: database, database-administration, db2

I see the following commands:

- `drop event monitor`
- `set event monitor`
- `create event monitor`

But nothing like list event monitor or get event monitor. Is there a DB2 command to list all current event monitors?

I'm currently using DB2 9.7 but am interested in answers for other versions as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can query the system catalog table `SYSCAT.EVENTMONITORS` to get a list of the event monitors defined in your database:

```
select evmonname, event_mon_state(evmonname) as enabled
  from syscat.eventmonitors
```

The second column will return 1 for active event monitors, and 0 for inactive event monitors.

This query will work for all versions of DB2 on Linux, UNIX or Windows.

Comment: Are there any commands that don't include "select"?

Comment: No.  All event monitors are stored in the system catalog.